# How to override CMake cache variable

Tags: cmake

I have the following line in CMakeLists.txt:

```
set (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS yes CACHE BOOL "Build shared library or not")
```

In the GUI, this would allow (I assume) unchecking the box after initially running CMake. However, I need to be able to disable building shared libs from the command line. How can I override `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` from the command line?

Comment: Add -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=no to your CMake call?!

Comment: Does set define the variable if it's already defined?

Comment: I'd say yes, but I guess that if your set command is executed afterwards, it might get overwritten.

Comment: That's the point. It's not my project it's someone else's that I'm using as a library.

Comment: It's not really a duplicate, because you need to modify the CMakeLists.txt. But it looks like that is probably the only solution, and there are enough unanswered questions to go around.